# how to save the employee details including image in mysql db?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, spring-mvc

My requirement is to save the employee details(including image) into mysql db.i want to save the image location in db .And actual image(binary formate) should save into server? Iam using spring.Iam not getting how to do this.Plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the image into the database, you'll need to set the field type to a BLOB.

The link below might help you out.

Reference: [MultipartFile / blob problem saving in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358837/multipartfile-blob-problem-saving-in-database)

Reference: http://www.coderanch.com/t/300850/JDBC/java/save-image-database-blob

Comment: Hi,I want to save the image location in db and actual image should store into server..

Comment: Hopefully this link will help you http://gardiary.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/file-upload-and-download-using-spring-mvc/