# SpringMVC-FileUpload - HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am new to spring and trying to Upload an image using **spring 4.2.7** and **commons-io-1.3.2**,**commons-fileupload-1.3**,**jdk 1.8**.

But unfortunately I am getting error i.e HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Please help.

Code snippet is

formExamplePage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Form Example</h2>
    <form:form commandName="formExample" action="formExampleDetails" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>User Name:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="userName" placeholder="User Name"></form:input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Salary:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="salary" placeholder="salary in decimal"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Gender</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="M" label="Male"/>
                    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="F" label="Female"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Profile Photo:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="profilePhoto" type="file"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller class is ApplicationController.java

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
@RequestMapping(value="/formExampleDetails",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String formExampleDetails(@ModelAttribute FormExample formExample,
            @RequestParam("profilePhoto") MultipartFile profilePhoto,ModelMap model){

        System.out.println("User Name====>"+formExample.getUserName());
        System.out.println("BirthDate====>"+formExample.getBirthDate());
        System.out.println("Gender=======>"+formExample.getGender());
        System.out.println("Salary=======>"+formExample.getSalary());
        System.out.println("ProfilePhoto=>"+profilePhoto.getOriginalFilename());

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Pojo Class i.e FormExample.java is

```
package com.spring.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Date;

public class FormExample implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5527691555730303451L;

    private String userName;
    private Date birthDate;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private Blob profilePhoto;
    private Character gender;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public Blob getProfilePhoto() {
        return profilePhoto;
    }
    public void setProfilePhoto(Blob profilePhoto) {
        this.profilePhoto = profilePhoto;
    }
    public Character getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(Character gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

spring configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring"></context:component-scan>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="./"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"></property>
    </bean>        
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this question on multipartFiles and blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358837/multipartfile-blob-problem-saving-in-database)? Your form:form may require enctype="multipart/form-data" .

I haven't tried to run your code, but have you tried to either remove, rename  profilePhoto and its getter and setter from FormExample, or set its type to MultipartFile ?

I suspect that despite your controller method having a parameter with the same name Spring might be trying to assign the parameter value to both the method parameter and the form property, and failing to convert MultipartFile to java.sql.Blob when assigning to the form property.

Comment: Thank you @X.D.F,  I have added enctype="multipart/form-data" in the formExamplePage.jsp and modified the file name to something different i.e  <td>
           <input name="testing" type="file"/> 
       </td>                                                                                                     and modified the controller class accordingly. Now it works perfectly.